# Regex to determine if a string starts with more than one capital letter

Tags: regex

I am trying to determine if a string has more than 1 capital letter in a row at the start of a string. I have the following regex but it doesn't work:

```
`^[A-Z]{2,1000}`
```

I want it to return true for:

- ABC
- ABc
- ABC ABC
- ABc Abc

But false for:

- Abc
- AbC
- Abc Abc
- Abc ABc

I have the 1000 just because I know the value won't be more than 1000 characters, but I don't care about restricting the length.

I am working with PHP, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wouldn't leaving the second one do it?

```
^[A-Z]{2,}
```

Which basically says "string starts with 2 or more capital letters"

Here's some tests with the strings you provided that should match:

```
>>> 'ABC'.match(/^[A-Z]{2,}/);
["ABC"]
>>> 'ABc'.match(/^[A-Z]{2,}/);
["AB"]
>>> 'ABC ABC'.match(/^[A-Z]{2,}/);
["ABC"]
>>> 'ABc Abc'.match(/^[A-Z]{2,}/);
["AB"]
```

And then the ones it shouldn't match for:

```
>>> 'Abc'.match(/^[A-Z]{2,}/);
null
>>> 'AbC'.match(/^[A-Z]{2,}/);
null
>>> 'Abc Abc'.match(/^[A-Z]{2,}/);
null
>>> 'Abc ABc'.match(/^[A-Z]{2,}/);
null
```

If you only want to match the first two, you can just do `{2}`

Comment: "I am working with PHP, if it makes any difference." -- from the original question.

Comment: I had a small error in the code surrounding the checking. Fixed and it's all working now! Thxs

Comment: As I noted below, you actually only need `{2}` as well - the comma is unnecessary.

Comment: I have actually gone one further than changed the regex to [A-Z]{2,} I'm trying to determine if a string should be changed to lower case, by looking for more than 1 capital letter in a row.

Answer (score 3):

I ran `^[A-Z]{2,}` through the [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/) for egrep searches, and your test cases worked.

Comment: Yeah, my bad otherwise. Oh well, question is posted and it might help someone else :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `^[A-Z][A-Z]`

Answer (score 2):

So do you want it to match the entire line if the first 2 letters are capital?  If so, this should do it...

```
^[A-Z]{2,}.*$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
php > echo preg_match("/^[A-Z]{2}/", "ABc");
1
php > echo preg_match("/^[A-Z]{2}/", "Abc");
0
```

`/^[A-Z]{2}/` seems to work for me. Since you're doing a substring match anyways, there's no need to do `{2,}` or `{2,1000}`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your regex works fine at finding which line begins with 2 caps, i assume you had another question.

Maybe you have case insensitve on

Try

```
(?-i)^[A-Z]{2,}
```

Or maybe you meant "match the whole line"

```
(?-i)^[A-Z].*$
```

Answer (score 1):

non regex version

```
$str="Abccc";
$ch = substr($str,0,2);
if ( $ch == strtoupper($ch) ){
    print "ok";
}else{
    print "not ok";
}
```

Comment: no need to. But if you want, you can also use strcmp() as well. check the excellent PHP documentation for more info .

Comment: Both are strings and so this wouldn't be a useful test criteria. So the triple equals doesn't seem necessary, to me.

Answer (score 0):

In one word here is the answer in regex.

```
^[A-Z]{2,} or ^[A-Z][A-Z]+
```

whichever looks easier to you :)